# Sqlite3 synthax error while joining tables using PDO

Tags: php, pdo, sqlite

I have a problem with PDO and sqlite3. While trying to join tables I am getting an error:

```
object(PDO)#1 (0) { } {"error":true,"message":"SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 near \u0022FROM\u0022: syntax error"
```

my connection and sql query looks like this. The sublime-text 2 also does not color `JOIN` like others.

```
$objDb = new PDO('sqlite:../dbase/shopping-list');
    var_dump($objDb);
    $objDb -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "SELECT `i`.*,  
            `t`.`name` AS `type_name`
            FROM `items` `i`
            JOIN `types` `t`
            ON `t`.`id` = `i`.`type`
            ORDER BY `i`.`date` ASC";
    $result = $objDb->query($sql);

    if(!$result) {

        throw new  PDOException("The result returned no object");

    }
```

I follow a tutorial and he can use this statement with mac. I use arch linux but I dont think so it is related. 
When I check sqlite database with cli, I can get the `types` table :

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM `types`;
1|Qty
2|Kg
```

Is there anyway to accomplish this query ?

edit : I have changed db and removed backticks ... Now I can get the items but still I have an error and they dont work inside my angularjs frontend.

```
object(PDOStatement)#3 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(37) "SELECT * FROM types ORDER BY id" } {"error":false,"items":[{"id":"1","item":"Butter","qty":"1","type":"1","done":"0","date":"2014-10-06 02:45:51","type_name":"Qty"}],"types":[{"id":"1","name":"Qty"},{"id":"2","name":"Kg"}]}
```

here is correct sql query with JOIN

```
  $sql = "SELECT item.* ,
                        t.name AS type_name
                        FROM items item
                        INNER JOIN types t
                        ON t.id = item.type
                        ORDER BY item.date ASC";
```

this is my [select.php link](http://pastebin.com/iWF48eH0)

Comment: I followed a tutorial the guy was forming database table names with backticks. I am adding my cli view in the question.

Comment: SQLite does apparently allow backticks for MySQL compatibility https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html Did you copy/paste this code or hand-type it? There shouldn't be anything off before the `FROM` clause, but if there's some invalid non-printable character in there it could cause problems.

Comment: Try: ON (`t`.`id` = `i`.`type`) -- I've always used parentheses around a JOIN condition (though I agree the error messages suggests this isn't the problem)

Comment: Sorry my connection was lost.I have hand-typed. trying to both comments.